# Router-outlet creates a gap or space in my Angular app with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I use Bootstrap 4 in my Angular 2 app and I'm facing a problem with the directive router-outlet.

Here a screen :

[image]

And my code :

**AppComponent**

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <div class="row bg-warning">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/login">Sign in</a></li>
        <li><a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/register">Sign up</a></li>
        <li><a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/chat">Chat</a></li>
        <li><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="row flex-grow-1 bg-danger">
    <router-outlet ></router-outlet> <!-- class="d-none" -->
  </div>

</div>
```

the component nested in the router-outlet above

**ChildComponent**

```
<div class="col d-flex flex-column h-100 bg-success">
<div class="row flex-grow-1 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <img title="logo" src="assets/logo.png" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

This code creates the red gap in the screen capture and if I uncomment the class attribute "class="d-none"" and I put it in the router-outlet attribute the red gap disappears.

So is it normal or there is an alternative to this ?

Comment: I'm assuming it's due to the `flex-grow` class. What can you gather from devtools?

Comment: FF devtools acts the same when I delete router-outlet from the DOM. What can I do with flex-grow to avoid that  ?